# Sagemaker Inference Endpoint with fitted Encoder

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

So as I don't get any help by reading documentations and blogposts I ll ask over here:

I want to deploy a Sagemaker Endpoint with fitting a Sagemaker Pipeline. I want to have an endpoint which is backed by a PipelineModel. This PipelineModel should consist of two models: A fitted model which encodes my data and a model which predicts with an XGBoost estimator. I follow along this docu: [enter link description here](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_inference_pipeline/Inference%20Pipeline%20with%20Scikit-learn%20and%20Linear%20Learner.html)

But this example doesn't show how to integrate the fitted preprocessor model in a PipelineStep. What Step do I have to use? A TrainingStep? Thanks in advance. I am desperate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this official example: [Train register and deploy a pipeline model](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/train-register-deploy-pipeline-model/train%20register%20and%20deploy%20a%20pipeline%20model.ipynb).

The two variations to keep in mind:

1. For **models that need training** (usually for those based on tensorflow/pytorch), a TrainingStep must be used so that the output (the model artifact) is correctly (and automatically) generated with the ability to use it later for inference.
2. For **models generated by a simple fitting on the data** (e.g., a scaler with sklearn), you can think about creating a TrainingStep in disguised (it is an extra component in pipeline, it is not very correct to do it but it is a working round) but the more correct method is to configure the preprocessing script so that it internally saves a model.tar.gz file with the necessary files (e.g., pickle or joblib objects) inside it can then be properly used in later steps as model_data. In fact, if you have a model.tar.gz, you can define a Model of various types (e.g., an SKLearnModel) that is already fitted.

At this point, you define your PipelineModel with the trained/fitted models and can either proceed to direct endpoint deployment or decide to go through the model registry and keep a more robust approach.

Comment: Thank you so much! So If I use a Processing Step e.g with the FrameworkProcessor and make sure that the encoder is saved via joblib or even better as a model.tar.gz I can create a model out of this in a CreateModelStep???

Comment: ...and do I need the script mode?

Comment: I do not know exactly which preprocessing you want to do, but in general you have more control with script mode. Your reasoning is correct and in line with my answer. 
Remember that joblib creates the file, but in a ProcessingStep it is not automatic that the output is put into a model.tar.gz (which is true for TrainingSteps). So you will have to use a library such as tarfile to put the models generated for preprocessing into it.